# EF6 : Populate a list in one entity with objects from another table

Tags: entity-framework

So, I have 2 entities, Page (shown below) and Button (not shown).

```
public class Page
{
    public Page()
    {
        Command_Type = Command_Type.Navigation;
    }

    public int ID { get; set; }

    public IList<Button> Buttons { get; } = new List<Button>();
    public IList<Button> StaticButtons { get; } = new List<Button>();
}
```

In the Entity above there are 2 Lists, Buttons that are specific to each Page and StaticButtons that are shared between every Page.

Each button has a property called IsStatic and this defaults to false.

My question is how can I populate the StaticButtons List with Buttons that are shared between pages (i.e. where Button.IsStatic = true).

Comment: What you're trying to do (as-is) may be impossible as EF6 does not allow separate entity collection properties that use the same element type, as that would require ambiguous `DbSet<T>` collections. But alternatives may be possible. Please post the definition of `class Button` - and please tell us what you're using for the FK.

Comment: Where is `Command_Type` defined? Your `class Page` isn't `partial`. (Also, you shouldn't be using underscores for identifiers in C# except for constants and in xUnit projects).

Comment: Also, avoid using the term `Static` for your `IsStatic` property, because it's ambiguous w.r.t. C#'s `static` keyword.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EF6 cannot differentiate between `Buttons` and `StaticButtons`: they're both `Button` collections, so - if you try to use your code as-is I expect it will fail when you instantiate your first `DbContext`.

Instead, consider this approach, where `class Page`'s collections are read-only views over the "real" single `Button` collection:

```
public class Page
{
    public Page()
    {
        Command_Type = Command_Type.Navigation;
    }

    public int ID { get; set; }

    internal ICollection<Button> AllButtons { get; } = new HashSet<Button>(); // Consider using a HashSet<T> instead of List<T> for entity collections, if appropriate.

    public IEnumerable<Button> Buttons       => this.AllButtons.Where( b => b.IsStatic == false );
    public IEnumerable<Button> StaticButtons => this.AllButtons.Where( b => b.IsStatic );

    public void AddButton( Button b ) => this.AllButtons.Add( b );
}
```

- You'll need to manually write your `Page` entity `Configuration` method that configures EF to map `Page.AllButtons` instead of `Page.Buttons` to the FK between `Button` and `Page` (which you haven't posted, so I had to make assumptions here).
- The `AddButton` method here is naive and buggy: it does not prevent duplicates or perform any validation.